# Why won't my python program work from the command line?

Tags: python, compilation

This is my code, in TestHash.py, and it won't compile. When I type python TestHash.py nothing prints on the command line.

```
#import Hash.py
from Hash import *


def testHash(radix, modulus, fName):
    print("Using radix " + str(radix) + " and modulus " + str(modulus) + ".")
    print("  Input  |  hash value")
    file = open(fName)
    for line in file:
        for word in line.strip().split(' '):
            if (word != ''):
                print('{0:10s} {1:8d}'.format(word, hash(word, radix, modulus)))
```

Comment: When is the function supposed to run?

Comment: You don't seem to be calling the function. Try adding `testHash(1,2,'3')` or something similar to the end of your file.

Comment: the testhash() function should act like a main function and the user is supposed to enter values for radix, modulus, and fName on the command line

Comment: And you never called it, so it never ran.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your whole program, then the program is actually running. It does not seem to run because everything is inside a function. The function is not automatically run - you need to call it to run it.

To call the function add this line to the end of your code:

```
testHash(radix, modulus, fName)
```

replacing `radix`, `modulus`, and `fName` with the proper values.